# Any way to filter out the most frequent terms in Neo4J APOC request?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I have the following request:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','context:34b4a5b0-0dfa-11e9-98ed-7761a512a9c0') 
 YIELD rel, start, end WITH DISTINCT rel, start, end 
 RETURN DISTINCT start.uid AS source_id, 
 start.name AS source_name, 
 end.uid AS target_id, 
 end.name AS target_name, 
 rel.uid AS edge_id, 
 rel.context AS context_id, 
 rel.statement AS statement_id, 
  rel.weight AS weight
```

Which returns a table of results such as [image]

The question:
Is there a way to filter out the top 150 most connected nodes (`source_name/source_id` and `target_name/edge_id` nodes)?

I don't think it would work with `frequency` as each table row is unique (because of the different `edge_id`) but maybe there's a function inside Neo4J / Cypher that allows me to count the top most frequent (`source_name/source_id` and `target_name/edge_id`) nodes?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking for the 50 most common `start/end` node pairs?

Comment: @cybersam yes, exactly. the 50 or 150 most frequently occurring pairs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query might do what you want:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO','context:34b4a5b0-0dfa-11e9-98ed-7761a512a9c0') 
YIELD rel, start, end
WITH start, end, COLLECT(rel) AS rs
ORDER BY SIZE(rs) DESC LIMIT 50
RETURN
  start.uid AS source_id, 
  start.name AS source_name, 
  end.uid AS target_id, 
  end.name AS target_name,
  [r IN rs | {edge_id: r.uid, context_id: r.context, statement_id: r.statement, weight: r.weight}] AS rels
```

The query uses the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COLLECT` to collect all the relationships for each pair of `start/end` nodes, keeps the data for the 50 node pairs with the most relationships, and returns a row of data for each pair (with the data for the relationships in a `rels` list).

Comment: Thank you, it works! Do I understand correctly that it counts how `rels` have the most similar `start` and `end` node pairs and then filters out the top 50 of them? Can I somehow integrate the `weight` parameter of the relationship `rel.weight` into this calculation?

Comment: The only problem is that it filters out the top 150 relationships, so that's not necessarily 150 nodes and my graph is directed... I wonder how it could be possible to filter out the top 150 nodes with the highest degree from those results and then show the relationships for them...

Answer (score 1):

You could always use `size( (node)-[:REL]->() )` to get the degree.

And if you compute the top-n degree's first you can filter those out by comparing

`WHERE min < size( (node)-[:REL]->() ) < max`

Comment: Thank you, Michael. But how do I integrate it into my query? Can I add `WHERE size(rel)` right after the `WITH DISTINCT` part of the query? And I'm still not clear how I filter out the top 150 ones... Will be great if you could clarify that!